# Private wrapper customized to work with public apps - XERO API?

Tags: php, api, oauth

I'm trying to customize the PHP Private App wrapper on [Github](https://github.com/XeroAPI/PHP-Xero) to work with Public apps.

I see that the class by default calls this class:

```
$this->signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_Xero($this->public_cert, $this->private_key);
```

which is then extended by this class - OAuthSignatureMethod_RSA_SHA1.

I know that public apps use HMAC_SHA1 so OAuthSignatureMethod_Xero class actually needs to extend OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1.

What i'm unsure of is what functions go inside this:

```
class OAuthSignatureMethod_Xero extends OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1 {
   - ?
   - ?
}
```

Everything else in the class looks like it should work fine with private,public or partner apps.

Has anyone done this? or know how to?

I'm quite new to Oauth and APi's so I'm struggling to customize it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the Xero-API-PHP-CLASS,
https://github.com/mediabeastnz/Xero-API-PHP-Class

its pretty easy to use. I tested with a public type an works fine.
Cheers,
Christian

Comment: Haha yes that is my own wrapper that I built as I was unable to figure that out. I recently updated it also.